# How do I rip a dvd including menus and extras to a menu driven divx file (or any lossy format that supports menus)?

Tags: command-line, dvd, multimedia

I am asking exactly [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18889/how-to-archive-play-dvd-with-menus-and-all-to-disk) for the same reason, but would like to archive dvds as small, low quality video, while preserving the menu choosing experience.

I would like to rip my dvds to something that has the same menus but whose video is in a much more compressed format.  I do not want to copy a dvd to an .iso image.

How can this be done in the most automatic (hopefully CLI) way possible?  Any format is fine so long as playback on linux is possible.

Comment: Do you need the **menus**, or just chapters, choice of sub-titles (more than one, on/off), and sound channels (5.1, etc.)?  There should be a method of menu capture (to text based file), based on either image (snapshots) or full video (short video clips), that is open-source.  ***Is there one out there?***  (If so, what tools support it?

Comment: I'd prefer the menus (and think they'd probably be easier) but if someone can manage to infer menu entries by OCRing the menu screens, I'm sure that's worth the bounty!

Comment: I currently use DeVeDe, but the menus and chapter selection is re-created (in other words, the original menu is lost). Maybe this is a temporary solution... :P

Comment: `k9copy` is definitely the way to go.  Make a much smaller ISO of your DVD.  Then to watch later, just mount the ISO and point your favorite DVD player at it.

Answer (score 2):

Try Dvdrip.

> Dvdrip is a full-featured DVD copy program written in Perl. It
>   provides an easy to use, but feature-rich Gtk+ GUI to control almost
>   all aspects of the ripping and transcoding process. It uses the widely
>   known video processing swissknife transcode and many other Open Source
>   tools. dvd::rip itself is licensed under GPL / Perl Artistic License.<sup>1</sup>

To Install Dvdrip, do that from the USC

[image]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source: [Ubuntu Documentations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DVD::Rip)</sup>

Another program is [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/).  I don't think it can do menus, but take a look at it, you might use it for other projects.

I just stumbled upon AcidRip DVD Ripper.  You can install it from USC.  From reading about it, I think it can do menus, but I'm not sure.  I* will test it once I'm done with the project I'm working on.

[image]

Take a look at this:

> k9copy provides the following features:
>
> - The video stream can be compressed to make the video fit on any    configurable target size
> - DVD Burning
> - Transcode DVD using mencoder or ffmpeg with configurable presets
> - Creation of ISO images
> - The possibility of choosing which audio and subtitle tracks to copy
> - Title preview (video only)
> - The ability to preserve the original menus <sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Apps Directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DVD::Rip)</sup>

[image]

Comment: I tried installing it and ripping a sample DVD to see if it would give me menus, but it [stuck at 30 minutes](http://i.imgur.com/liG7R.png)

Comment: Actually, after I gave this answer, I tried it, and it worked fine, I'm on my 17th DVD.

Comment: If it gives you menus, I owe you the bounty.  I've just got to wrangle my version to make sure it works.  (I think you'll get 25 points of bounty anyway since you've got the highest rated answer)

Comment: @JohnBaber Make sure it works first.

Comment: I did get it to copy one title, but it didn't preserve menus :(

Comment: @Mitch FYI, it appears (to me at least), that k9copy is no longer available via the software centre, and I haven't found anywhere else to get it either, so I don't know if you want to edit the answer.

Comment: @JoeTait Thanks.  You're right.  I've removed the info.  But its still available at [Ubuntu Apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/virtualbox-qt/).

Comment: Seems they both can't do menus...

Answer (score 0):

For followers, if you just want to rip the menu you can do so on the command line, basically copy /media/username/diskname/VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB to wherever you want.  Won't have menu capability but will have the backing video.  Or re-encode it.

You can also rip the rest and re-encode it to be smaller: https://superuser.com/questions/749416/rip-cd-dvd-with-ffmpeg