# Ripping DVDs with menu

Tags: dvd, dvd-backup, disk-ripping

I used [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150379/how-do-i-rip-a-dvd-including-menus-and-extras-to-a-menu-driven-divx-file-or-any) and have ripped a DVD to back it up using dvd::rip. Although it doesn't seem to actually rip the menu, it does rip everything as a seperate file, which is what I would expect and is obviously fine.

However, it only seems to ripping in to .vob format (I have set it to go to .avi). Also, it is ripping in to files that are 22 minutes long (This does not relate to chapters on the dvd at all).

I am quite sure I have followed the manual, thought I don't know how up to date it is. If there are any very easy tools to "glue" together the files then that would also be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ubuntu forums had a few solutions after I asked here - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2166602

In particular ripping the whole iso, using

```
dd if=/dev/dvd of=/path/dvd.iso
```

seems to do exactly what I wanted